# Computer restarts itself

Tags: windows-10, boot, motherboard, sleep, shutdown

Problem description:

- On shutdown -> After shutting down  the pc, the power-LED starts blinking some minutes until the computer restarts itself. Everytime the power-LED blinks, the fan start moving for a short time.
- On restart -> The computer shutdowns, but instead of restarting immediately, it does the same like on shutdown.
- Switching to the sleep mode -> Instead of switching to the sleep mode, the computer shut down and restart like on shutdown.

Seems like the problem isn't related to any software, as it happen with windows, ubuntu & uefi. I already tested it with a new mainboard (same model, but new), but it didn't help. It occurs since I built the pc.

Hardware:

```
CPU: Intel Pentium G4560 2x 3.50GHz So.1151 BOX
Mainboard: ASRock H110M-DVS R3.0 Intel H110 So.1151 Dual Channel DDR4 mATX Retail
Power adapter: 350 Watt Cougar STX 350 Non-Modular 80+
RAM: DDR4 4GB (don't remember the exact model)
UEFI-Version: 1.20 (latest)
```

What I already tried:

- Start computer without case-cables
- Update BIOS to 1.20

Comment: Any chance of it being a stuck/faulty power button? I had similar issues and playing around with the case power button solved my problem. PS: there are a few questions recently asked that are v. similar to this. You could check the answers given in those to try solve your problem.

Comment: Good question, I don't know. Is there a way to start the computer without a power button? | I'll try some things, but til now, I couldn't find something what helped me.

Comment: there will be a pair of cables from the power button on your case to the motherboard, if you remove these from the motherboard pins, you just need to short the 2 "pwr" pins (using a screwdriver) to power on the PC. https://static.spiceworks.com/images/how_to_steps/0009/6625/b90debac7f258a9337d74a1419d3c9ce0889ac0f34a1d5b5484b0e59e7ff78d1_panel_1_.JPG

Comment: I don't think this issue is because of power button because if power button stuck machine will be suddenly turned off.

Comment: I started the pc without any cables of the case (like @TiO) explained, but there's still the same problem. I didn't remove the mainboard out of the case, but I don't think it would make a difference.